# model.rowCount() won't bind to Item's property

Tags: qt, qml, scrollview, qtquickcontrols2

I have a `ListView` which is initialized with a custom C++ model named `rootModel` inside Qml.
The model inherits `QAbstractListModel` and defines a `QVector<customType>` as a private member to populate the model.

In my `ApplicationWindow` I have created a `Dialog` in which I change the model and call the `setList()` function to update it. This works fine.

I also want to connect the model's size to a `ScrollView`'s `int` property. This property will define the `children` of a `RowLayout`.

The problem is that when I try to bind this property to the model's size, the application crashes.

FYI, all the modifications of the model follow the Qt's rules. `rowCount()` is `Q_INVOKABLE`. I have also tried using the `onModelChanged` handler but this didn't work (I have checked in the documentation that this signal is emitted when `modelReset()` is emitted, which is taking place inside `setList()` through `endResetModel()`

I believe this is a straightforward procedure (have already performed property bindings many times in my project) but doesn't work as expected.

I quote some sample code of my project.

```
//main.qml
ConfiguredChannels{
    id: configuredList
    anchors{
        left: parent.left
        top: devices.bottom
        right: tabs.left
        bottom: parent.bottom
    }
}

TabArea {
    id: tabs
    y: toolBar.height
    x: parent.width / 8
    anchors {
        top: toolBar.bottom
    }
    width: 3 * parent.width / 4
    height: 3 * parent.height / 4
    countPWM: configuredList.model.rowCount() //This is where I want to bind.
}


//ConfiguredChannels.qml
id: confChanView
header: confChanHeader
model: ChannelModel{
    id: rootModel
    list: channelList
}

//TabArea.qml
Item{
id: tabAreaRoot
property alias channelsPWM: channelsPWM
property int countPWM
ScrollView{
            id: scrollPWM
            anchors.fill: parent
            contentItem: channelsPWM.children
            horizontalScrollBarPolicy: Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOn
            RowLayout{
                id: channelsPWM
                spacing: 0
                Layout.fillHeight: true
                Layout.fillWidth: true
                Component.onCompleted: {
                    var namesPWM = [];
                    for (var i=0; i<countPWM; i++){
                        namesPWM.push("Channel"+(i+1));
                    }
                    createChannels(countPWM, "PWM", channelsPWM, namesPWM);
                }
            }
}
```

**[EDIT 1]**
After looking closer I realized that with my current implementation, even if I bind properly to the model's size I would still not be able to create the desired amount of `RowLayout`'s `children` on demand (after I change the model in the `Dialog` `Configuration.qml`).

That is because I have put their creation inside `RowLayout`'s `Component.onCompleted` handler. The content of this handler will be executed once the `Configuration.qml` will be initialized inside `main.qml`for the first time. After that, any other change to the `countPWM` will not make a difference since the Component is already Completed! Please **correct me** if I am wrong at this point.

Based on that, I have followed another implementation. I have created a "wrapper" function of `createChannels`, named `createStrips(countPWM)`. This way, to update properly the `RowLayout`'s `children` I have to call this function.

```
\\Configuration.qml
\\more code
currentModel.setList(newList)
tabs.createStrips(tableModel.count) \\tableModel is used to populate the newList that will be set to the model
newList.clear()
\\more code

\\TabArea.qml
function createStrips(countPWM){
    var namesPWM = [];
    for (var i=0; i<countPWM; i++){
        namesPWM.push("Channel"+(i+1));
    }
    createChannels(countPWM, "PWM", channelsPWM, namesPWM);
}


function createChannels(counter, channelType, channelParent, channelMapping){
    if ( channelParent.children.length !== 0){
        console.log("destroying");
        for ( var j = channelParent.children.length; j > 0 ; j--){
            channelParent.children[j-1].destroy();
        }
    }

    for (var i=0;i<counter;i++){
        var component = Qt.createComponent(channelType+".qml");
        if( component.status !== Component.Ready )
        {
            if( component.status === Component.Error )
                console.debug("Error:"+ component.errorString() );
            return; // or maybe throw
        }
        var channels =component.createObject(channelParent, { "id": channelType+(i+1), "channelText.text": channelMapping[i]});
    }
```

**[EDIT 2]**
Although the solution in EDIT 1 works and produces the right `children` for my `ScrollView` I don't think it is good enough and I believe the best implementation would be to bind the model's size change with the call to the `createStrips(countPWM)` function. Something like:

```
\\main.qml
ConfiguredChannels{
id: configuredList
anchors{
    left: parent.left
    top: devices.bottom
    right: tabs.left
    bottom: parent.bottom
}
onModelChanged: tabs.createStrips(model.rowCount) //or an appropriate signal handler defined on C++ side
}
```

And perhaps even better, make the creation of the `children` as a custom `qml` signal handler that will be emitted every time the model's size is changed. (I tried the `onModelChanged` as above but didn't work. Probably I am missing in which case is this signal emitted)

**[SOLUTION]**

I followed the instructions of the accepted answer as well as this [link](http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qtbinding.html#receiving-signals).

I added a `Q_PROPERTY` to my model's definition inside the header file named `rowCount` with the `NOTIFY` `rowCountChanged` as well as the signal `void rowCountChanged();` . Also, inside the function `setList(newList)` which I use to update the model, I added at the end of its implementation the `emit rowCountChanged();` . Last I connected this signal with my function `createStrips(count)` inside QML. Now every time the model's size is changed, my `ScrollView` will update automatically the strips shown as the `RowLayout`'s children.

```
\\ChannelModel.h
...
Q_PROPERTY(int rowCount READ rowCount NOTIFY rowCountChanged)
...
signals:
void rowCountChanged();

\\ChannelModel.cpp
void ChannelModel::setList(ChannelList *list)
{
beginResetModel();
...
endRestModel();
emit rowCountChanged();
}

\\main.qml
Connections {
    target: configuredList.model
    onRowCountChanged: tabs.createStrips(configuredList.model.rowCount)
}
```

Comment: Dis you try to find the error that cause to crash with debugger? What is a line where the application crashes? What are error messages? Please provide all relevant code, including the model.

Comment: Oops, I have overlooked the crash part in the question. Please provide a minimal example of your model, on which you call `rowCount()`, if this is what makes your app crash. Binding to `Q_INVOKABLE`s is not a real binding since there is no change notification.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Only the q-property allow a binding, in your case the `Q_INVOKABLE` is not, so you will have to create it, for this we use the signal `rowsInserted` and `rowsRemoved` as shown below:

***.h**

```
    Q_PROPERTY(int rowCount READ rowCount NOTIFY rowCountChanged)
public:
    ...
signals:
    void rowCountChanged();
```

***.cpp**

```
//constructor
connect(this, &QAbstractListModel::rowsInserted, this, &YourModel::rowCountChanged);
connect(this, &QAbstractListModel::rowsRemoved, this, &YourModel::rowCountChanged);
```

***.qml**

```
countPWM: configuredList.model.rowCount // without ()
```

Note:

I'm assuming that when you add an element or remove it, you're using:

```
beginInsertRows(QModelIndex(), rowCount(), rowCount());
//append data
endInsertRows();
```

Or:

```
beginRemoveRows(QModelIndex(), from, to)
// remove
endRemoveRows();
```

Comment: I followed your advice but the application still crashes. Inside `setList()` I do use the the signals you mention preceded by `beginResetModel()` and followed by `endResetModel()` . I tried to connect these with `rowCountChanged` but they are protected.

Comment: @K.Tsakalis 
It is not that you have an election, it is what must be done, Qt obliges it, beginXXX and endXXX notify at sight, they are not signals, they are functions. On the other hand rowCountChanged is a signal that I have created, it is not a method.

Comment: @K.Tsakalis rowsInserted and rowsRemoved are signals  http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html#rowsInserted http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html#rowsRemoved

Comment: @K.Tsakalis To understand the use of beginXXX and endXXX, check the following: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/model-view-programming.html#an-editable-model , 
I emphasize beginXXX and endXXX are mandatory

Comment: @K.Tsakalis probably your application crashed by a bad implementation, so if you do not show a [mcve] help it would be impossible.

Comment: Your advice was correct. The only thing different is that my model object is not created on the C++ side but inside QML . I studied this link http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qtbinding.html#receiving-signals and made the connection inside QML instead of the constructor. Now I can connect my function `createStrips(count)` with the model's size change. I will edit my question to show the solution. Thank you for your support.

Comment: @K.Tsakalis  you say you've used: QAbstractListModel, that is, you have implemented the class in C ++, then you can create it in QML and my solution works. :)

Comment: Sure. I didn't know the difference though of where to make the connection. In the doq link it explains in which side it should be performed depending on where the respective object is created. :)

Answer (score -1):

You can't bind to a `Q_INVOKABLE` since there is no association to a change-signal.

Create a `Q_PROPERTY(count READ rowCount NOTIFY rowCountChanged)` or something like that. Make sure that the signal `rowCountChanged` is emitted when rows are inserted or removed.

Of course it would be more canonical if you had a

```
 Q_PROPERTY(count READ count NOTIFY countChanged)

 int count() { return rowCount(); }
```

and make sure to emit `countChanged`.

Then you can bind to the property `count`.